# Laravel - Bulk insert on duplicate key update large data set

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have approx 80k records that I need to run an insert/update script on several times per day.

```
INSERT INTO `my_rankings` (`id`, `rank`) VALUES (1,100),(2,99)(3,102)...(80000,3) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `rank` = values(`rank`);
```

These records are currently in an array format:

```
$rankings = [
  ['id' => 1, 'rank' => 100],
  ['id' => 2, 'rank' => 99],
  ['id' => 3, 'rank' => 102],
  ...
  ['id' => 80000, 'rank' => 3],
]
```

Is there a nice / performant way I can run the above mentioned update query?

I have looked at Eloquent's `Model::updateOrCreate(...)`. However I don't think I can use this for bulk insert/updates.

I want to avoid using `foreach` on my `$rankings` array and insert/updating individual records, because the script will take far too long.

I have an answer for this question below https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815725/1239122, however it is far from elegant.

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution - It's not elegant, but very fast. 1.6s for 80k records.
Any better solutions would be much appreciated.

```
$allResults = [
    ['id' => 1, 'rank' => 100],
    ['id' => 2, 'rank' => 99],
    ['id' => 3, 'rank' => 102],
    ...
    ['id' => 80000, 'rank' => 3],
];

$rankings = [];
foreach ($allResults as $result) {
    $rankings[] = implode(', ', ['"' . $result['id'] . '"', $result['rank']]);
}

$rankings = Collection::make($rankings);

$rankings->chunk(500)->each(function($ch) {
    $rankingString = '';
    foreach ($ch as $ranking) {
        $rankingString .= '(' . $ranking . '), ';
    }

    $rankingString = rtrim($rankingString, ", ");

    try {
        \DB::insert("INSERT INTO my_rankings (`id`, `rank`) VALUES $rankingString ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `rank`=VALUES(`rank`)");
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        print_r([$e->getMessage()]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget to do string escapes too, to prevent against sql injection attacks

Answer (score 3):

Use database transactions.

```
DB::beginTransaction();
foreach ($bajillionRecords as $record) {
    $record->update();
}
DB::commit();
```

This will store your changes then commit them to the database when you run commit(). You could also do this as a closure:

```
DB::transaction(function() { /* */ });
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but still very slow. Takes over 2 minutes for 80k records, even if I chunk the `$bajillionRecords`.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?