# Laravel 5.5 - update or create bulk insert

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to preform update or create action on many records using laravel model.
Normal insert with updateOrCreate works perfectly with foreach but i want to avoide it as it slowing things down.
I have something like 200k records.
Is there is any way to achive it?
I tried this answer below
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34815725/1239122
But it is not super elegant.
Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this package: https://github.com/yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key

Comment: Maybe [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/performant-way-to-mass-update-or-create) post from laracast helps, if its still important.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a way to bulk insert or update in one query. But I have managed with only 3 queries. I have one table name `shipping_costs`. Here I want to update the shipping cost against the shipping area. I have only 5 columns in this table `id`, `area_id`, `cost`, `created_at`, `updated_at`.

```
// first get ids from table
$exist_ids = DB::table('shipping_costs')->pluck('area_id')->toArray();
// get requested ids
$requested_ids = $request->get('area_ids');
// get updatable ids
$updatable_ids = array_values(array_intersect($exist_ids, $requested_ids));
// get insertable ids
$insertable_ids = array_values(array_diff($requested_ids, $exist_ids));
// prepare data for insert
$data = collect();
foreach ($insertable_ids as $id) {
$data->push([
    'area_id' => $id,
    'cost' => $request->get('cost'),
    'created_at' => now(),
    'updated_at' => now()
]);
}
DB::table('shipping_costs')->insert($data->toArray());

// prepare for update
DB::table('shipping_costs')
->whereIn('area_id', $updatable_ids)
->update([
    'cost' => $request->get('cost'),
    'updated_at' => now()
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `insert()` in Query Builder to bulk insert. But update statement needs conditions. Please read the document:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can not do it for the update as you need to check the condition for the update, But you can do it for insert

```
  $data = array(
   array('name'=>'John', 'phone'=>'1234567890'),
   array('name'=>'Deo', 'phone'=>'9876543210'),
     //...
    );

Model::insert($data);
```

Comment: Thanks but this one is not answering my question. bulk insert is working as expected, i am trying to achieve update or create on many records using bulk insert